# Laravel 5 new session on every request

Tags: php, angularjs, session, laravel, laravel-5

I have got the following setup:
Laravel5 and AnguarlJS
Angular in the frontend send $http requests to Laravel5 backend.
The frontend is on test.example.com and the backend on api.example.com
The problem that I have got at the moment is the following.
The site tests when launching if the user has got an open session if it has got an token inside it which matches our database.
If not the user can login with his credentials like normal. When logging in the token created is saved to our database successfully and the token should be saved to a session item. When this is done it is again checked if the user is logged in correctly but apparently the session is empty.
We noticed that Laravel creates a new session for every request we do from AngularJS. The reason might be that a request with JS from an different subdomain is a cross domain request and the browser does not send the cookie to identify with the session. This might be the reason.

Apparently I do not know a solution to this problem.

Comment: try to set the domain to `'domain' => '.example.com',` in `config/session.php` file

Comment: I had this the whole time this was not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just done the following now since I worked on this many hours today.
I have edited my nginx config to serve the api not on the subdomain but also on a subfolder. My config looks like this:

```
location /api {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    index index.php;
    alias /srv/www/htdocs/api/public;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    ## Check for file existing and if there, stop ##
    if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
    }

    ## If we get here then there is no file or directory matching request_filename ##
    rewrite (.*) /api/index.php?$query_string;

    ## Normal php block for processing ##
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the web is stateless, just using header information or the domain could result in a man in the middle attack. Anything that comes from the client can be modified or replicated, including the cookie data. I do not have an answer to your exact problem here but I would recommend a different strategy.

One practice to use when communicating with an api is to use an access token with secure requests; similar to the oauth2 client/server relationship. By sending a token in the XHR or CURL requests to your api, the system can better validate whom it is talking to. Otherwise you could potentially run into people spoofing your authenticated users.